# Size of extended jframe?

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe, maximize-window

How can I get the width and height of an extended JFrame? (done through)

```
setExtendedState( getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: uhm whats wrong with calling `getWidth `and `getHeight` after setting JFrame to `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`

Comment: It gives me only the previous set width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `frame.setVisible(true)`:

```
double width = frame.getSize().getWidth();
double height = frame.getSize().getHeight();
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to my comment:

> uhm whats wrong with calling getWidth and getHeight after setting
>   JFrame to JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH

are you sure you call it after `JFrame` is visible and size state has been changed? i.e:

```
frame.setExtendedState( getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

System.out.println(frame.getWidth()+" "+frame.getHeight());
```

Another solution is simply get the screens size via

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
System.out.println("Screen Bounds: " + bounds );
```

as that would be the size of `JFrame` in `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` state

Comment: +1, almost... what if you have 2 monitors or more? :) -last time didn't worked for me: my frame was only in 1 monitor

Comment: @matheszabi good question perhaps going through all connected monitors and accumulating their widths/heights would do the trick

Comment: Your solution does work but there are some catches to it, as matheszabi said, and it does not depend on jframe aso. Eng. Fouad gave the right answer

Comment: @AndrewG.H. **Eng. Fouad gave the right answer* yes he did but also I said to call `getWidth()`/`getHeight()` on `JFrame` after setting it extended forgot to say visible, which I added in my answer. It would be better to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) next time, as than I and others could have seen you were not calling it before `JFrame` is visible/`pack()` is called

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.getContentPane().getSize();
```

You will lose the decoration title bar size. Or get the rootPane, even better.

Comment: It does not work, It gives me still the previous set dimension.